# How to update file in datasnap rest server with http?

Tags: delphi, rest, upload, datasnap

my question is as tittle.I have a datasnap rest server,I want upload file with java or java script.How do? (best have sample code)
thank your very much!

Comment: You send a PUT request, same as you would with any other kind of HTTP server that you wanted to send a file to. I suspect that's not really what you're asking about, though. Would you care to provide some more details in your question? Which part of the task are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thank you. I have the datasnap server and datasnap client,and this upload file function  between server and client  is ok. But now another client (java,or js) will call this function  to send file to server. I want to only use old datasnap server with http (like http://server/method/function/param1... ,one param is file content).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've once tried to pass a stream to a REST call, but eventually
resorted to uploading with a direct WebBroker request to a page...
which is easier to manage. That's not trivial either, as you'll have to manage the multi-part request data that you receive when you use a form to let the user pick the file to upload.

This is some of the code I'm using in WebModuleBeforeDispatch:

type TMyIdHTTPAppRequest = class (TIdHTTPAppRequest);

```
    haReq := TMyIdHTTPAppRequest(Request);
    fname := IntToStr (haReq.ContentLength);
    multi := TMultipartRequestFiles.Create(haReq.FRequestInfo,
      haReq.content);

    if (multi.Count > 0) and Assigned (multi.Items[0]) then
    begin
     theFile := TFileStream.Create(ServerConf['fileupload:tempdir'] + folder + '\' +
        multi.Items[0].FileName, fmCreate);
      multi.Items[0].Stream.Position := 0;
      TheFile.CopyFrom(multi.Items[0].Stream, multi.Items[0].Stream.Size);
      theFile.Free;
```

However it is based on a custom TMultipartRequestFiles that I have, trying to clean it up and load it as part of my Relax open source extension to Delphi datasnap.

Any other solution to manage file uploads?  I guess there should be something ready to use in Indy, I wrote that class many years ago.